# Start the bonding process with a remote bluetooth device

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth

I have managed to make an android device and scan and enlist all bluetooth devices in the area..I have the mac address of a remote device i just discovered in form of string and i want to start the bonding process with it.. i try `BluetoothDevice` object and then method `createBond()` but its not communicating with the remote device to pair..
Here is the code

```
class BluetoothM: AppCompatActivity{
// mac address of remote bluetooth device
string address;
//the discovered devices are listed in a ListView so i call a listview item click method to start pairing
 private void Dlist_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
        //the mac address has already been assigned in the OnReceive broadcast Receiver
          if (e.Position == e.Id)
            {
              //Get the default adapter of the device
                BluetoothAdapter adapt = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
              //Get the remote device based on its MAC address
                 BluetoothDevice device = adapt.GetRemoteDevice(address);
              //start the pairing process for the device
                device.CreateBond();
            }
        }



}
//This class discovers bluetooth devices and pass MAC address to our string address for use in the listview click method
[BroadcastReceiver(Name = BluetoothDevice.ActionFound, Enabled = true)]
    public class DeviceDiscovered : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            string ac = intent.Action; string name;
            if (BluetoothDevice.ActionFound.Equals(ac))
            {
                BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice)intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);
                //add bluetooth name and address if they do not already exist
                if (!MainActivity.avail.Contains(device.Name + "\n" + device.Address))
                {
                    MainActivity.avail.Add(device.Name + "\n" + device.Address);
                    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, MainActivity.avail);
                    MainActivity.dlist.Adapter = arrayAdapter1;
                     //address assigned a value
                    MainActivity.address = device.Address; MainActivity.name = device.Name;
                    MainActivity.mydevice = device;
                }

                
            }
            Toast.MakeText(context, "Received the intent", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
```

The remote device is not receiving this communication and i don't know why, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Check you have `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission in Manifest. Register for ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED intents to be notified when the bonding process completes, and its result. Get the result of device.CreateBond(), it returns false on immediate error, true if bonding will begin.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#createBond()